# Pipes duplicate output on terminal

Tags: terminal, process, pipe, ipc, stdout

```
hellofork.c ∗​ ​ :
/*​ * Simple Hello world program with 2
processes.
*/ #include <stdio.h>
main() {​ printf("\%d:
Hello\n", getpid());
if (
!fork() )
printf("\%d: world\n", getpid()); 
}​
```

If we add a pipe to the program more (a filter to watch content sequentially one screen at a time) the output is:

```
terminal~> ./hellofork |
more terminal~> 53438:
Hello terminal~> 53438:
Hello terminal~> 53440:
world
```

Why does this happen

Comment: The issue is simply buffering.  When you are writing directly to the tty, the output is line buffered so the first 'Hello' is flushed from the internal buffer before the `fork`.  When you pipe the output to `more`, the data is block buffered so it is not flushed.